# Ember You must include an 'id' for customer in an object passed to 'push'

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-router

I am using ember 2.7.0.I got the following data from resp API,

```
{
"accounts": [
{
  "id": "57a3660793d4ba3a5b78a780",
  "status": null,
  "crid": "Someone",
  "deleted": false,
  "accountInfo": {
    "iccid": "accountId",
    "iccidValue": "accountValue"
  },
  "subscriptionInfo": null
},
{
  "id": "57a3660793d4ba3a5b78a780",
  "status": null,
  "crid": "Someone",
  "deleted": false,
  "accountInfo": {
    "iccid": "accountId",
    "iccidValue": "accountValue"
  },
  "subscriptionInfo": null
}
],
"user": {
"id": "288607702394",
"isdn": "491622897075",
"pcc": null
}
}
```

Created Model for Customer which contain details of all the accounts,users etc:

**Customer.js (Model)**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    device:DS.hasMany('device'),
    user:DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

**accounts.js(Model)**

```
status: DS.attr(),
id: DS.attr(),
status: DS.attr(),
crid: DS.attr(),
deleted: DS.attr(),
accountInfo: DS.attr(),
subscriptionInfo: DS.attr()
```

**User.js (Model)**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
isdn: DS.attr(),
pcc: DS.attr()
});
```

Created serializer for all the above 3-Models

**Customer.js**

```
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType){
console.log("Entered normalizeResponse",payload );
return this._super(...arguments)
}
});
```

**Device.js**

```
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'id'
});
```

**user.js**

```
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
primaryKey: 'id'
});
```

Issue is while running the application i am getting the following issue in chrome console : **Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for customer in an object passed to 'push'**

I do not know how to assign 'id' for customer model.Actually i would like to assign user model id as customer model is that possible? How can achieve it in customer model serializer?In the normalizeResponse of customer serializer i am  able to see my response.

Note : I cannot modify the rest response.So option is left with modification of ember data model.

The way i am calling the REST API GET in my controller is

```
var customer = this.store.findRecord('customer',    this.get('customerID')).then((customer) => {
    console.log("customer::",customer);
  },(resp,status) => {
    console.log("resp:status:",resp,status);
  });
```

It always entered in to the error response.

Your help should be appreciable.

Comment: Where is customer part in payload you mentioned in question?

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani  we do not have customer part in the payload but I want to store entire content as a customer object with the primary key as user object user ID is that possible in ember? Sorry I am entirely new to ember please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani What kind of ember model you will suggest for this json?

Comment: You cant. Ember model means a persisted object. It means it should be in a db. You can use normal object for your need

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani sorry I'm not getting you.how can we achieve that?

Comment: Create a model by `export Ember.Object.extend(...` in a separate file in an arbitrary folder named `customer.js`. Then use it as non-persistent model. A normal object/class.

Comment: You cant use that customer in `store` or `adapter` because it is not a persistent model. So customer should be an simple Ember object

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you are storing your data and what type of API you are using but in my experiences (using a PHP or Loopback api) I have set the id variable able to be null (not required). On the database side I have used mySQL and I set the id field to auto increment. Ember already expects the ID and does not allow you to edit or create the id